# KOMA-script thumb index with scrlayer-scrpage: Shift text inside chapterthumbbox

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, chapterthumb

I want to make semicircle thumb indices using chapterthumbs in KOMA-script. For this, I made circles with tikz and shifted them by the appropriate distances on odd and even pages, respectively. Of course, this also shifts the chapter number. I have tried using `\hspace*{}`, but this either shifts the entire thumb index or does nothing.

How can I shift the text inside the thumb index *differently* on odd and even pages? Or do I have to make separate chapter thumb commands for odd and even pages? (I hope not)

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%%---thumb indices using chapterthumb

% the following bases on an example in the KOMA-Script book:
\newcommand*{\firstchapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbskip}{\firstchapterthumbskip}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.01\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\colorlet{chapterthumbboxcolor}{gray!30}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbcolor}{white}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}
\newkomafont{chapterthumb}{\normalfont\Large\color{\chapterthumbcolor}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\chapterthumb@box{%
    \usekomafont{chapterthumb}%
    \parbox[c][\chapterthumbheight][c]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm, fill=chapterthumbboxcolor]
        {\chapterthumbformat};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbbox}{%
    \if@mainmatter
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>\z@
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\z@
    \else
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\chapterthumbformat}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\lastchapterthumbformat\else
    \stepcounter{chapterthumb}%
    \global\let\lastchapterthumbformat\reserved@a
    \fi
    \@tempcnta=\numexpr
    \dimexpr
    \paperheight
    -\firstchapterthumbskip
    -\chapterthumbwidth
    -\lastchapterthumbskip
    \relax / \dimexpr
    \chapterthumbskip
    \relax
    +1
    \relax
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\@tempcnta
    \else
    \setcounter{chapterthumb}{0}%
    \fi
    \vspace*{%
        \dimexpr
        \firstchapterthumbskip
        + ( \chapterthumbskip )
        * \value{chapterthumb}%
        - \baselineskip
        \relax
    }\par
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \hspace*{0.9cm}
    \else
    \hspace*{-1.4cm}
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapterthumb}
\setcounter{chapterthumb}{10000}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbformat}{\relax}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
background,%
outermargin,%
contents=\chapterthumbbox
]{chapterthumb}

\newcommand*\EnableChapterthumb{%
    \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{chapterthumb}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}}%
}
\newcommand*\DisableChapterthumb{%
    \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}

\EnableChapterthumb

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{First}

    \lipsum[1-6]

    \chapter{Second}

    \lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason I'm using circles instead of semi-circles is that after printing, the pages might be cut slightly differently. This poses the danger that there is a small white space between the thumb index and the outer edge of the page.

Comment: If I understood your question then something like this could work in the box command: `\ifodd\value{page}\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{-1cm}\chapterthumbformat}
         \else\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{1cm}\chapterthumbformat}\fi`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this works when put inside the tikz environment. If you make an answer out of it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MWE containing the answer according to Ulrike Fischer's comment:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%%---thumb indices using chapterthumb

% the following bases on an example in the KOMA-Script book:
\newcommand*{\firstchapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbskip}{\firstchapterthumbskip}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.01\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\colorlet{chapterthumbboxcolor}{gray!30}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbcolor}{white}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}
\newkomafont{chapterthumb}{\normalfont\Large\color{\chapterthumbcolor}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\chapterthumb@box{%
    \usekomafont{chapterthumb}%
    \parbox[c][\chapterthumbheight][c]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=2.5cm, fill=chapterthumbboxcolor]
        {\ifodd\value{page}\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{-1cm}\chapterthumbformat} \else\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{1cm}\chapterthumbformat}\fi};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbbox}{%
    \if@mainmatter
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>\z@
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\z@
    \else
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\chapterthumbformat}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\lastchapterthumbformat\else
    \stepcounter{chapterthumb}%
    \global\let\lastchapterthumbformat\reserved@a
    \fi
    \@tempcnta=\numexpr
    \dimexpr
    \paperheight
    -\firstchapterthumbskip
    -\chapterthumbwidth
    -\lastchapterthumbskip
    \relax / \dimexpr
    \chapterthumbskip
    \relax
    +1
    \relax
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\@tempcnta
    \else
    \setcounter{chapterthumb}{0}%
    \fi
    \vspace*{%
        \dimexpr
        \firstchapterthumbskip
        + ( \chapterthumbskip )
        * \value{chapterthumb}%
        - \baselineskip
        \relax
    }\par
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \hspace*{0.9cm}
    \else
    \hspace*{-1.4cm}
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapterthumb}
\setcounter{chapterthumb}{10000}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbformat}{\relax}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
background,%
outermargin,%
contents=\chapterthumbbox
]{chapterthumb}

\newcommand*\EnableChapterthumb{%
    \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{chapterthumb}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}}%
}
\newcommand*\DisableChapterthumb{%
    \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}

\EnableChapterthumb

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{First}

    \lipsum[1-6]

    \chapter{Second}

    \lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```